# can we use both class name and input type name in the same click function

Tags: jquery, html

I had a functionality of multiple checkbox..in which if we check multiple childs need to be checked and vice versa. BUt it is only happening on the third click.
if we click the allcheck all childs are checked and vice versa.. but the functionality i need is if even one child is checked and if we click allcheck remaining need to be checked..and if we uncheck even one child allcheck needs to be unchecked.I used this code

html:

```
<li class="inputradio"><input name="allCheck" type="checkbox" ></li>

<li id="childcheckbox"><input name="childCheck" type="checkbox"></li>
```

all check

```
<div id="actions"><div id="box">
<ul><li class="inputradio"><input name="allCheck" type="checkbox" ></li>
<li class="multiple"><a href="#" class="bt btleft">Multiple</a></li>
 <!--<li class="deletebutton"><a href="#" class="bt btleft">Delete</a></li>
<li class="copy"><a href="#" class="bt btright">Copy</a></li>-->
 <li class="shatebutton"><a href="#" class="bt stmiddle">Share</a>
<div id="smenu">

</div>
```

child:

```
 <div id="rightoutputimgae">
<div id="rightimgId" class="rightimg"  rel="tooltip" 
content="<img src='jqe13/image/1.jpg' class='tooltip-image'/> ">
 <div id="outputimageId" class="outputimage">
<img src="jqe13/image/1.jpg" alt="Right Bottom Image"></div>
</div>
<ul><li id="childcheckbox"><input name="childCheck" type="checkbox"></li>
<li id="outedit"><a href="#"><img src="jqe13/image/edit_s.PNG" alt="edit" title="Edit">
 </a></li>
<li id="outdelete">
<a href="#" onclick="deleteImg()">
 <img src="jqe13/image/delet_c.PNG" alt="delete" title="Delete"></a></li>
  <li id="outfullscreen">
   <a href="#"><img src="jqe13/image/fullscreen_c.PNG" alt="Full Screen" 
class="fullscreen" title="Full Screen"></a></li>
```

jquery:

```
 $('.inputradio').click(function () {
    $('input[name=allCheck]').click(function () {
        $("input[name='childCheck']").prop('checked', this.checked);
    });

    $("input[name='childCheck']").click(function () {
        if ($('input[name=childCheck]:checked').length === $('input[name=childCheck]').length) $('input[name=allCheck]').prop("checked", true);
        else $('input[name=allCheck]').prop("checked", false);
    });
});
```

can anyone tell me what is wrong in this

Comment: sorry..check the edited code

Comment: Don't assign click handlers from inside another click handler - every time `.inputradio` is clicked you'll add additional click handlers to the inputs.

Comment: also all the things in brackets `[]` should be in quotes after the equals sign. `[name=childCheck]` should be `name="childCheck"]`

Comment: i'm new to jquery..how can i put class and name at the same time

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[name=allCheck]').click(function () {
    $("input[name='childCheck']").prop('checked', this.checked);
});

$("input[name='childCheck']").click(function () {
    if ($('input[name=childCheck]:checked').length === $('input[name=childCheck]').length) $('input[name=allCheck]').prop("checked", true);
    else $('input[name=allCheck]').prop("checked", false);
});
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
var allchk = $('input[name="allCheck"]').click(function(){
    chks.prop('checked', this.checked);
})

var chks = $("input[name='childCheck']").click(function () {
    allchk.prop("checked", chks.filter(':checked').length === chks.length);
});
```

Comment: i've put in doc ready..but its not working..its working only if i put the inputradio class and that too on the third click.the checkbox all and child are in diff div..

Comment: @madhu there are no checkbox with name `childCheck`

Comment: oops..check it now pleasee

Comment: can you recreate the issue in jsfiddle

Comment: actually eerything working fine jsfiddle. but if i integrate in my project..its not working..the control is not going to chidcheckbox

Comment: jsfiddle.net/D4YV8/3 just check the fiddle..if i put it in my code it just nt wrking the same

Comment: because the checkbox name is different http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rcg9V/1/ in your html the checkbox name is `outCheck` where as my script it is `childCheck`

Comment: i've changed the name..consider it is outCheck

Comment: @madhu what are you saying http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rcg9V/1/ seems to be working

Comment: the code i posted is working too..but if i integrate it..without the input radio class it isn't working.. i think click handler within another click handler won't work

Comment: @madhu you should not have the outer click handler in my code I have removed it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.inputradio').click(function () {

  if ($('.inputradio input').is(':checked')) {
    //do something
  }
  if($('#childcheckbox input').is(':checked')) {
    //do smoething else
  }
});
```